# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

Tags: android, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-android

I am getting below error when i use resttemplate in my android application.I am getting this error when i use resttemplate in my code.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.lss.loop, PID: 17285
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
                  at com.esp.office.services.ServerAuthenticateService.<init>(ServerAuthenticateService.java:240)
                  at com.esp.office.authentication.AccountGeneral.<clinit>(AccountGeneral.java:30)
                  at com.esp.office.view.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:138)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5459)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the code.

```
this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList();
    messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    this.restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    this.restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new C07681());
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new C07692());
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new C07703());
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new C07714());
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, new C07725());
    this.gson = builder.create();
```

and the Exeption after inserting data that I debug and Find out Exception is for this :

```
this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Below is my graddle configuration :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.esp.office"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:2.0.0.M3') {
        exclude module: 'spring-core'
    }
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:2.0.0.M3'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

build.gradle :

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
 }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }

 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What is the reason for the above error.Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Looks like your version on a dependency isn't compatible.

Comment: @JonathanJohx which one??

Comment: I'm gonna add the asnwer

Comment: Try wit old `spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya not working

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's missing repositories of maven in your gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
} repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}
```

You can see [spring-android-documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/)

Comment: I don't see it in your gradle code.... @KJEjava48 can you add the repositories part on your question?

Comment: it's in the outer build.gradle file i will update it in my question.

Comment: i have updated the code with both build.gradle files. check now

Comment: Remove allProjects and repositories will be outside, do you think that is necessary to override allProjects task? How many projects do you have?